# How to specify fields delimiter when import MySQL into Hive with Sqoop?

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hive, sqoop

I tried to import a MySQL table into Hive with Sqoop v1.4

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysqll//localhost:3306/mysqldb \
--username user --password pwd --table mysqltbl \
--hive-import --hive-overwrite \
--hive-table hivedb.hivetbl -m 1 \
--null-string '\\N' \
--null-non-string '\\N' \
```

There are 100 rows in `mysqltbl` where one of the fields `text` contains `\t` and `\n`, resulting in Sqoop parsing the data incorrectly, i.e. there were more than 100 rows in `hivetbl` and the fields were not aligned.

Instead of escape the special characters in MySQL, how to specify the delimiters of fields and records in Sqoop?

Comment: You can try to use orc, parquet or avro instead of simple text format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `--hive-import`, it will create hive table for you **IF NOT EXISTS**. It will create with Hive's default delimiter - fields terminated by : CTRL A and  lines terminated by : `\n`

As per drill [docs](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html#_importing_data_into_hive):

> Even though Hive supports escaping characters, it does not handle escaping of new-line character.
>
> Hive will have problems using Sqoop-imported data if your database’s rows contain string fields that have Hive’s default row delimiters (`\n` and `\r` characters) or column delimiters (`\01` characters) present in them. You can use the `--hive-drop-import-delims` option to drop those characters on import to give Hive-compatible text data. Alternatively, you can use the `--hive-delims-replacement` option to replace those characters with a user-defined string on import to give Hive-compatible text data.

You can simply use `--hive-drop-import-delims` in your query and it will drop `\n`.

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysqll//localhost:3306/mysqldb \
--username user --password pwd --table mysqltbl \
--hive-import --hive-overwrite \
--hive-table hivedb.hivetbl -m 1 \
--hive-drop-import-delims \
--null-string '\\N' \
--null-non-string '\\N' \
```

If you want to replace your own string (say space i.e. " "), you can use `--hive-delims-replacement`.

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysqll//localhost:3306/mysqldb \
--username user --password pwd --table mysqltbl \
--hive-import --hive-overwrite \
--hive-table hivedb.hivetbl -m 1 \
--hive-delims-replacement " " \
--null-string '\\N' \
--null-non-string '\\N' \
```